# Dynamic script to change specific variables in Angular 2 or higher

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently, you can use the user's final script. This script can modify some previously available variables. 
I created a small example in pure javascript I would like to do the same in angular 2+ https://jsfiddle.net/hxs3d0hu/2/

Thank you in advance for your attention

HTML Code

```
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="descricao">Nome</label>    
          <input type="text" id="descricao" name="descricao" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="valor">Valor</label>
          <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" value="10" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="quantidade">Quantidade</label>  
          <input type="text" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" value="20" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="total">Total</label>  
          <input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="codex">Code</label>  
          <textarea id="codex" name="codex" rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control">
          if (qtde &lt; 15) {
              vlr = 10;
          } 
          else 
          {
              vlr = 9;
          }
          tot = vlr * qtde;
          </textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="button" id="calcular" name="calcular" onclick="calcularx();" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
    var vlr = 0;
    var qtde = 0;
    var tot = 0;

        function calcularx(){
            var valor = document.getElementById("valor");
            var quantidade = document.getElementById("quantidade");
            var total = document.getElementById("total");

            vlr = valor.value;
            qtde = quantidade.value;
            tot = 0;

            tot = qtde * vlr;
            total.value = tot;

            var codex = document.getElementById("codex").value;
            var cst = document.getElementById("customcodescript");
            var corpo = "function custom(){ {0} }".replace("{0}", codex);
            //cst.innerHTML = corpo;
            load_js(cst, corpo);

            custom();

            valor.value = vlr;
            quantidade.value = qtde;
            total.value = tot;

            console.log(tot);
        }

       function load_js(cst, corpo)
       {
          if(cst != null){
            cst.remove();
          }
          var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
          var script= document.createElement('script');
          script.id = "customcodescript";
          script.type= 'text/javascript';
          script.innerHTML = corpo;
          //script.src= 'source_file.js';
          head.appendChild(script);
       }

    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    }
    NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
        for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
                this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plnkr that would achieve what you're looking for.

http://embed.plnkr.co/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU/

You create a function with eval, then call it using the component context. All the function and variable in your component will be available to your textbox code :

The template
    Value:

```
<label>Code:</label>
<textarea [(ngModel)]="code"></textarea> <br>

<button (click)="executeCode(code)">Do it.</button>
```

The component :

```
export class HelloWorld {

  value = 100;
  code = 'this.value = this.value * 100';

  executeCode(code){
    let fn = eval("(function(){ {0} })".replace("{0}", code));
    fn.call(this);
  }
}
```

However, keep in mind that eval is usually evil and that this use case is quite weird. I'm not sure if your user should control the code. Anyhow, that's up to you.

Also, if you want to avoid the "this." in the code text box, you can always use replace on your variable name to add it behind the scene.